# Javascript Bundle Definition in Plone 5

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

I have define my Resource Directory in configure.zcml:

```
<plone:static
    type="plone"
    name="stuff.dropdownmenu"
    directory="static" />
```

I have define my JS Resource in registry.xml:

```
<records
    prefix="plone.resources/stuff"
    interface='Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.IResourceRegistry'>

    <value key="js">++plone++stuff.dropdownmenu/stuff.js</value>

</records>
```

My Question: What is the right value of the Element-Tag in the Bundle Definition:

```
<records
    prefix="plone.bundles/stuffdropdown"
    interface='Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.IBundleRegistry'>
    <value key="resources" purge="false">
        <element>???<element>
    </value>
    <value key="enabled">True</value>
</records>
```

Is it the `stuff` part of prefix-Attribute or `++plone++stuff.dropdownmenu/stuff.js` ?

best regards

Answer (score 1):

I found in [CMFPlone registry.xml](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/profiles/dependencies/registry.xml#L1058) that the part of prefix is the right option. The Resource Definition [is here](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/profiles/dependencies/registry.xml#L1058) in the same file: CMFPlone registry.xml